# Is it possible to have MDIO Phy and I2C Phy interface running on the same bus?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, i2c

I'm interfacing a Vitesse 8221 Phy and a KSZ8567STXI Phy on the same bus. Both interfaces do have the option of either i2c or mdio to access the their registers. However, with the hardware design we have right now, the vitesse 8221 is using mdio, but the KSZ8567STXI is using i2c. I do see the in the linux kernel version 4.X code for mdio and i2c. My question is, will Linux handle this situation after adding the appropriate device tree nodes and phy drivers?

Comment: Speed, voltage, addressing, word-lengths are all different, and one driver has no way of knowing when the other driver is using the bus.  Other than that, how did you like the play Mrs. Lincoln?

Comment: This is what I had in mind as well, and thank you for your response!